# Compressing coordinates in Fenwick tree

Tags: algorithm, optimization, fenwick-tree

Let's say we have **n** empty boxes in a row. We are going to put **m** groups of coins in some consequtive boxes, which are known in advance. We put the 1st group of coins in boxes from **i_1** to **j_1**, the 2nd group in boxes from **i_2** to **j_2** and so on.

Let be **c_i** number of coins in box **i**, after putting all the coins in the boxes. We want to be able to *quickly* determine, how many coins are there in the boxes with indexes  **i = s, s + 1, ... e - 1, e**, i. e. we want to compute sum

```
c_s +c_(s+1) + ... + c_e
```

efficiently. This can be done by using [Fenwick tree](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees). Without any improvements, Fenwick tree needs **O(n)** space for storing **c_i**'s (in a table; actually, **tree[i] != c_i**, values are stored smarter) and O(log n) time for computing the upper sum.

If we have the case where

- **n** is too big for us to make a table of length **n** (let's say ~ 10 000 000 000)
- **m** is sufficiently small (let's say ~ 500 000)

there is a way to somehow compress coordinates (indexes) of the boxes, i.e. it suffices to store just boxes with indexes **i_1**, **i_2**, ... , **i_m**. Since a value that is stored in **tree[i]** depends on binary representation of **i**, my idea is to sort indexes **i_1**, **j_1**, **i_2**, **j_2**, ... , **i_m**, **j_m** and make a tree with length **O(m)**. Adding a new value to the **tree** would then be straight forward. Also, to compute that sum, we only have to find the first index that is not greater than **e** and the last that is not smaller than **s**. Both can be done with binary search. After that the sum can be easily computed.

Problem occurs in 2D case. Now, we have an area of points **(x,y)** in the plane, **0 < x,y < n**. There are **m** rectangles in that area. We know coordinates of their down-left and up-right corners and we want to compute how many rectangles contain a point **(a,b)**. The simplest (and my only) idea is to follow the manner from the 1D case: for each coordinate **x_i** of corners store all the coordinates **y_i** of the corners. The idea is not so clever, since it needs **O(m^2)** = **too much** space. My question is

```
How to store coordinates in the tree in a more efficient way?
```

Solutions of the problem that use Fenwick trees are preferred, but every solution is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The easiest approach is using map/unordered_map instead of 2d array. In that case you even have no need in coordinates compression. Map will create a key-value pair only when it needed, so it creates log^2(n) key-value pairs for each point from input.
2. Also you could you segment tree based on pointers (instead of arrays) with lazy initialisation (you should create node only when it needed).
3. Use 2d Segment Tree. It could be noticed that for each canonical segment by y-coordinate you can build segment tree (1d) for x-coordinates only for points lying in zone y_min <= y < y_max, where y_min and y_max are bounds of the canonical segment by y. It implies that each input point will be only in log(n) segment trees for x-coordinates, which makes O(n log n) memory in total.